# Laravel and CUPS/IPP printing

Tags: php, laravel, cups

What is best or standard way, these days, to send file(PDF/text) to CUPS' printer from laravel . I mostly find older posts but no recent post regarding this topic.
 Few older packages like smalot/cups-ipp or  PHP::PRINT::IPP are there but I need thoughts from pros.?

Comment: Lets suppose 3 different persons will suggest you to use three different approaches. Those 3 persons are pros. What will you do? I assume you will have to check each option yourself, right? But what if only one person will answer you with non up-to-date approach? Will you stick to it because this person is "pro"?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny But still a valid approach to publicly ask for best practices, though, and hope to filter noobs by peer-pressure, isn't it?

Comment: I found smalot/cups-ipp with last update on march 2020 and a clean architecture my nuber one choice